# Is there any software real time photoshop

Tags: animation, graphics, photo, photoshop

Which we have seen in the link follows. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qrGOi41iwE

Let us know the software and tutorial if it is there..

Answer (score 0):

No, this is just video FX and nothing real.